# "Nothing" in Lookaround terms [RAKU]

Tags: regex-lookarounds, raku

I was reading in regexes documemtation about "Tilde for nesting structures".

The sideline explanation about the use of `<?>` is:

> Here `<?>` successfully matches the null string.

I assumed that I was able to use `<?[]>` instead of it, but it failed to do so!

As an example:

```
say so "" ~~ / <?> /;
say so "test" ~~ / <?> /;

say so "" ~~ / <?[]> /;
say so "test" ~~ / <?[]> /;
```

The response:

```
True
True

False
False
```

Could someone give me an explanation about this?

Comment: It is in line with other regex engines, an empty character class matches *nothing*, i.e. it is a regex that will never match any string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax `<?[]>` means a lookahead matching an empty character class. Observe that an empty character class also never matches:

```
say "x" ~~ /<[]>/   # Nil
```

A character class specifies a set of characters that could be matched. An empty character class implies an empty set of characters, and so cannot possibly match anything.